# View uploaded documents without having to download them every time - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload

I am not a developer, just a charity volunteer so bear with me please!!...

I would like to find a way to simply view files uploaded to contacts (for example under Activities, or Notes) without downloading them every time.

Example, I want to save a PDF of a letter under a Note. But every time I want to view the PDF, it downloads it, clogging up my PC....

How do I get around this problem??

Thank you and apologies if this is a super duper easy question...

Thanks

Anna

Answer (score 6):

As Pradeep implies, this isn't a CiviCRM issue but a web browser configuration issue.

I'm not sure what web browser you're using, but in Firefox, when I click on a PDF in an activity (see "1" below), I get a pop-up where I can select "Open With" (2) and "Do this automatically for files like this from now on" (3).  I imagine similar options exist for all the major web browsers.

[image]

Comment: Thank youuu :=)

Comment: Just to note that this will still download the file to your computer.  It's just that it will save the file in a temporary directory rather than saving it in your downloads directory.

Answer (score 3):

To view pdf rather downloading locally you will need to install a [PDF preview](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn?hl=en-US) "add on" in Chrome.

Or you can turn off PDF download from chrome settings

Navigate to Settings >> Advanced >> Content Settings >> PDF Documents. Turn off 'Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome'.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, and it still downloads every time :(....

Comment: Hi Anna, I have updated my answer to include second solution i.e turn off from chrome browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version, if you customize `civicrm/file` link to have `download=0` query string parameter in it, the file will be opened in a new tab instead of downloading. For eg, if the URL is

```
https://site-name/civicrm/file?reset=1&id=400&eid=622&fcs=<file_hash>
```

Adding download parameter will open the pdf/image in the new tab of the browser.

```
https://site-name/civicrm/file?reset=1&id=400&eid=622&fcs=<file_hash>&download=0
```

Comment: oh, that's interesting, where can you customize the file link?

Comment: It would need some customization in an extension. Maybe, use https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_links/, pageRun, etc?